# Redirection with httpclient

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpclient

I need to enter a web platform and after doing the login redirect to another URL, that is:

Using httpclient(c#/.net) in wwww.example.com to login, once logged in go to wwww.example.com/contacts.

I know how to login but not how to redirect.

```
var url = "https://scgi.duocom.es/cgi-bin/telefacil2/telefacil";
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";

httpRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9";

httpRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "es-CO,es;q=0.9,en-CO;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es-419;q=0.6";

httpRequest.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0";

httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

httpRequest.Headers["Origin"] = "https://www.telefacil.com";

httpRequest.Headers["Referer"] = "https://www.telefacil.com/";

httpRequest.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Dest"] = "document";

httpRequest.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Mode"] = "navigate";

httpRequest.Headers["Sec-Fetch-Site"] = "cross-site";

httpRequest.Headers["Sec-Fetch-User"] = "?1";

httpRequest.Headers["Upgrade-Insecure-Requests"] = "1";

httpRequest.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36";

httpRequest.Headers["sec-ch-ua"] = "" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"";}

httpRequest.Headers["sec-ch-ua-mobile"] = "?0";

httpRequest.Headers["sec-ch-ua-platform"] = ""Windows"";

var data = "google_id=&origen_alta=&account=USUER&password=PASSW&submit=Entrar";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{

   streamWriter.Write(data);

}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{

   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

}

Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not in english

Comment: @derpirscher : "Needs Details or Clarity" is typically used as a close reason for non-English questions (just an FYI)

Comment: correction performed

Comment: @HeiverC : can you also change the title of your question?  Thanks.  I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @devlin carnate, ready

Comment: @HeiverC :  I've already cast my vote to re-open.  You'll need to wait for others to vote to re-open.

Comment: and it is, see: [how to handle redirect from http response in c# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649175/how-to-handle-redirect-from-http-response-in-c-sharp-code)